# Euler characteristic of the projective plane (using embedding diagram)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space

> Make the square into the projective plane $\mathbb{P}$ by identifying edges and compute the Euler characteristic by embedding the following graph onto the surface:

[image: graph]

Here is my diagram of the identified square of the projective plane with the embedded graph on it:

[image: Projective plane]

Now I can see that $v=3$ and $e=4$ but I am unsure how to calculate the number of faces from this. According to my lecturer the answer is $2$ leading to an euler characteristic of $\chi(\mathbb{P})=v-e+f=3-4+2=1$.

> Could you explain why $f=2$ in this case?

Comment: Oh man, just read something else:) my bad!

Comment: e=4 because: A) there are 4 coloured line pieces? Or B) there are 2 couloured lines + 2 border lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see four squares in the figure. The two diagonally opposite squares form a face, as you can see from the gluing. That is why it has two faces in total.

Comment: thank you. I suppose for torus and klein bottle will have $f=1$ since the space 'wraps around' itself

Comment: @thinker exactly!