# Euler characteristic and fundamental polygon

Tags: algebraic-topology

How is it calculate the Euler characteristic of sphere using its fundamental polygon?

It is $V = 2, E = 2, F = 1$, so $\mathcal{X}(S^2) = 1$? (I know its 2, so there is something wrong)

And for the projective plane?

It is $V = 2, E = 2, F = 1$, so $\mathcal{X}(\mathbb{R}P^2) = 1$?

I saw this question, but it mention a graph: [Euler characteristic of the projective plane (using embedding diagram)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792337/euler-characteristic-of-the-projective-plane-using-embedding-diagram)

Regards!

Comment: How does the sphere have only one face? Could you say how the sphere is cut up into regions?

Comment: Sphere has this fundamental polygon, yeah? https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG7eW.png  But I don´t know how many vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image [i.stack.imgur.com/oG7eW.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG7eW.png) is $\mathbb{R}P^2$: 2 vertices, 2 edges, 1 face, and its Euler characteristic is $2-2+1=1$.

The corresponding picture for $S^2$ could look like the image [i.stack.imgur.com/lbGOz.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbGOz.png). There are 3 vertices, 2 edges, and 1 face, and its Euler characteristic is $3-2+1=2$. (How do I know there are three vertices and two edges? When you glue this, you are gluing the bottom edge to the left edge, and the right edge to the top edge. So the resulting "sphere" will have a blue edge and a red edge, a vertex at the start of the blue edge, a vertex between the two, and a vertex at the end of the red edge. There is no more gluing among the vertices.)